# Understanding the proof of nested interval theorem: uniqueness and existence

Tags: real-analysis

The is a proof in my textbook. First I have to proof, that there is precisely one $\xi$ which is in all nested intervals $I_n = [a_n,b_n]$ with the interval length $b_n-a_n = \frac{b_1-a_1}{2^{n-1}}.$

Assume there are two such real numbers which are contained in all of the nested intervals, then $|\xi'-\xi''|\le b_n-a_n = \frac{b_1-a_1}{2^{n-1}}, \: \forall n\in \mathbb N$.

The conclusion in the textbook is that $|\xi'-\xi''|=0 \implies \xi' =\xi''$. But $|\xi'-\xi''|$ could also be negative... This point has not been addressed??

Comment: If $\vert a\vert=0$ then $a=0$....

Comment: How the abs of a real number could be negative...

Comment: This is not what I'm asking about. If $|\xi'-xi''| \le b_n-a_n$ then $|\xi'-xi''| < 0$ or $|\xi'-xi''| = 0$. Why is the first not the case?

Comment: Oh, now understand. I made a very dumb mistake 

Comment: How do you deduce the first case?

Comment: @dmtri Sorry, I was not thinking.